# Use shift-up/down keys to mark/unmark lines in dired?

Tags: key-bindings, dired, region

The default in `dired` is to mark files and folders with <kbd>m</kbd>, and to unmark them with <kbd>u</kbd>. Instead of this, I'd rather like to use <kbd>shift-up</kbd> and <kbd>shift-down</kbd> for marking or unmarking lines (in a DWIM fashion). So <kbd>shift-up</kbd> would mark/unmark the current line and move the cursor one line up.

This is nothing particularly fancy, I guess, and I would preferably use something already built in into `dired` or provided by some extra package. But I haven't come across something like this so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dired has a function for toggling marks, `t`. However, it works on all files at once. We can use narrowing to restrict it to the current line only. With that feature sorted, the rest is fairly straightforward:

```el
(defun my-dired-toggle (arg)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))
    (dired-toggle-marks))
  (dired-previous-line arg))

(defun my-dired-mark-up ()
  (interactive)
  (my-dired-toggle 1))

(defun my-dired-mark-down ()
  (interactive)
  (my-dired-toggle -1))

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<S-up>") 'my-dired-mark-up)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<S-down>") 'my-dired-mark-down)
```

Comment: To use `narrow-to-region` and `widen` for every line sounds like overkill, but it's nevertheless working without noticeable slowdowns on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that `narrow-to-region` is particularly costly, and it saves us having to write our own toggle-mark function. Thinking about this some more, I think `save-restriction` is probably more appropriate here than `save-excursion`, and would allow us to remove the `widen` call.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you get similar behavior out of the box.

- Command `diredp-mark-region-files` marks the files in the active region.  (Similarly, `diredp-unmark-region-files` unmarks them.)
- And shift-selection with the cursor keys works to select text (active region).

Command `diredp-mark-region-files` is not bound to a key by default, but you can bind it.  E.g., if you bind it to, say `C-o` then just hit `C-o` after using, say `S-down...`.

There is a reason that simply using shift-selection (e.g. `S-down...`) does not, by itself, mark or unmark files: With Dired+ you can do ***lots*** of different things with the active region.  So the act of selecting is separated from the various actions on the selected files.

Another way to mark files using the region is to drag the mouse (`mouse-1`).  Just click `mouse-3` to then see a [whole bunch of things](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#DiredPlusPopupRegionMenu) you can do to the files in the region, one of which is to mark them.

[**`dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)